# Django South Error: "there is no enabled application matching 'myapp'"

Tags: python, django, django-south

So, I finally gave in and grabbed South. The problem is, every time I try to follow the tutorial and run

```
"python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial"
```

I get an error

```
"There is no enabled application matching 'myapp'"
```

--Things I have tried--

I have tripple checked my settings file, running Import South from the django shell returns no errors, and I have added manage.py containing folder to PYTHONPATH, as well as wsgi.py and settings.py.

I have run python manage.py and python C:\path\to\manage.py variants, even went into my python directory and verified that south was in the site-packages folder. syncdb runs fine, ending with "not synced (use migrations)". python manage.py migrate runs without returning errors but otherwise seems to have no effect. I have tried running the said command both before and after running syncdb, which has no effect on the outcome.

--Other potentially pertinent info--

Django 1.5.1, Python 2.7, no other external apps used, Windows 7 64 bit, python is added to the windows path, South installed via python setup.py install command. Installation completed successfully. I do not use a virtualenv, and would really prefer to avoid this as it would mean alot of refactoring of this current project's setup and wasted time. I plan to move to a virtualenv setup in the future, but not now.

What's going on? How do I fix this? Net searches revealed no good info at all, I am completely at a loss...

Comment: is `'myapp'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`? does `myapp/models.py` exist?

Comment: it does not exist, and really shouldnt exist. 'myapp' is the project's name, is that incorrect? does south apply only to a specific app within the project then? I have at least 6 custom apps with their own model.py files. Is there a command I should run for it to apply to the whole project instead?

Comment: @second, I think I know what I was doing wrong now. I was trying to use a command meant for a django APP on a django PROJECT. If I'm not mistaken, python manage.py migrate is the command which does the same thing but for the entire project. Do I still need to run shemamigration for each app first to initialize them though? If you add a formal answer, I can tag it as best answer. Thankyou for your time and help!

Comment: Just for the record, be careful when using tabs for autocompletion. I was getting this error because my autocomplete put 'myapp/' instead of 'myapp'.

Comment: I had model.py instead of models.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

migrations exist on a per-app basis. each app may or may not have its own migrations, but you need to create them for each app where you want to use them. (often all apps)

`./manage.py migrate` is a shortcut that runs migrations for all apps

Answer (score 7):

This error can be misleading: it is thrown not when South tries to import the app, but when it tries to get the app's `models` module.

- perhaps it cannot import the application (because you didn't add its name to `INSTALLED_APPS`)
- perhaps it cannot import the `models` module, because the file `models.py` does not exist, or because the directory `models/` does not contain an `__init__.py`.

South doesn't import the `models` module itself. Instead, it leaves that job to  `django.db.models.get_app('app_of_interest')`, which according to its docstring "Returns the module containing the models for the given app_label." The error message raised by `get_app` is, in fact, different depending on whether it failed to import the app or the model, but both exceptions are `ImproperlyConfigured`, and the `schemamigrations` script doesn't look any deeper than that.

Because South says it is accepting security updates only (it entered end-of-life with Django 1.7's migration feature), I'm not submitting a fix to its codebase, but instead documenting the problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Check once whether you have included the app name in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py